# Expression to give fiscal year in report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an expression in a report like so:

```
=Year(First(Fields!DepositDate.Value, "dsetCoverSheet")) Mod 100
```

This gives the last 2 digits of the year in DepositDate, e.g. if DepositDate is 7/1/2013, it gives 13.

What I need though, is fiscal year, which is from 7/1/2013 to 6/30/2014, so that 7/1/2013 gives a 14.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add 6 months to the date before applying the expression?

```
=Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month
    , 6
    , First(Fields!DepositDate.Value, "dsetCoverSheet")))
  Mod 100
```